# Understanding before_save in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

In the line above, I thought that before_save was a method. But changing it to the following stops it from working:

```
before_save({ self.email = email.downcase})
```

What is happening? Is it not a method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`before_save` is an [ActiveRecord callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) and is used to either execute a block of code such as the first code sample in your original post.

If you don't want to execute code within a block, perhaps what you need is too long for a simple block, you may also use this callback to call/execute a method of your own design as in the example below.

```
before_save :my_awesome_pre_save_method
# somewhere in your model (typically in a protected method)
protected
def my_awesome_pre_save_method
  self.email.downcase!
end
```

For the example you have shown (down-casing an email before saving), my sense is that the block approach is better than a method call.

Answer (score 8):

To clarify, because I feel the accepted answer did not address this at all, before_save absolutely is a method. The reason your code doesn't work isn't because before_save isn't a method, it's because in Ruby a block does not get passed to a method as a parameter, it goes after the method. If you wrote:

```
before_save() { self.email = email.downcase }
```

it should work without issue.

Comment: Both answers are great imo. I think you also deserve an upvote.

Comment: @SergioA. appreciate it. I hope my answer didn't come across as dismissing the other one, it certainly has useful information, I just wanted to make sure the specific "Is it not a method" part of the original question was addressed.